# GitHub pages page not build correctly?

Tags: github, markdown, jekyll

The GitHub pages page of my repository is built from the README, and everything worked fine, but since I added some images to the README.md, the page is a mess. Maybe it is because of the way I add the images? Or is is a Jekyll-bug?
This is the begging of the README.md file:

```
# Salty Engine
![version-badge](https://img.shields.io/badge/version-0.14.0-orange.svg) ![release-badge](https://img.shields.io/badge/release-0.12.5-brightgreen.svg) ![price-badge](https://img.shields.io/badge/price-free-red.svg) ![license-badge](https://img.shields.io/badge/license-MIT-blue.svg)
<p>

![salty-engine-logo](logos/logo_small.png)

Salty Engine is a Java library for making a whole 2D Game with only one single library/engine. It aims to be the most user-friendly and easy-to-use 2D Game making tool for Java.
```

[image: This is how the page looks]
[image: This is how the readme looks]

And lastly, the repo can be found here -> https://github.com/edgelord314/salty-engine
and the page here -> https://edgelord314.github.io/salty-engine/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `<p>` tag after your badges.

```
# Salty Engine
![version-badge](https://img.shields.io/badge/version-0.14.0-orange.svg) ![release-badge](https://img.shields.io/badge/release-0.12.5-brightgreen.svg) ![price-badge](https://img.shields.io/badge/price-free-red.svg) ![license-badge](https://img.shields.io/badge/license-MIT-blue.svg)
<p>  <=REMOVE THIS
```

On github.com Commonmark is used for Markdown parsing, while Jekyll uses a traditional Markdown parser. As [documented](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.28/#html-blocks) in the spec, CommonMark handles raw HTML differently than the original Markdown rules and that explains the difference in the output.

In [traditional](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html) Markdown, all content within a block level element is not parsed as Markdown text. And as HTML does not require a closing `<p>` tag, the Markdown parser is assuming everything after the opening tag is within that paragraph. In fact, if you look at the rendered HTML (use your browsers 'view source' or 'inspect' tool), you will see that there is in fact a closing `</p>` tag at the end of the document. In other words, the entire rest of the document is seen as being within a single block level raw HTML tag and therefore is not being parsed as Markdown (as per the rules).

However, CommonMark breaks from those rules by only following them if there are no empty lines within the raw HTML. However, as the first line after the opening `<p>` tag is a blank line, Commonmark immediately closes the `<p>` tag and then parses the rest of the document as normal Markdown text. Therefore, the page renders differently on github.com.

Comment: Thank you very much :). Solved the problem by removing the <p> tag

Comment: If this resolved the issue, then you should "accept" the answer by clicking on the check mark to the left.

Comment: yeah, sorry. I'm new to Stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

Github [uses GitHub Flavored Markdown](https://githubengineering.com/a-formal-spec-for-github-markdown/) (GFM) to render markdown files in your repository and show them in their web interface at github.com.

On the other side Github Pages / Jekyll uses Kramdown.

In order to instruct Jekyll to parse your markdown files, you have to add a front matter.

```
---
# this is an empty front matter
---
<p>Yolo</p>
```

Secondly, you have to [configure kramdown](https://kramdown.gettalong.org/parser/kramdown.html#options) to parse inside block elements.

In your **_config.yml** :

```
theme: jekyll-theme-hacker
kramdown:
  parse_block_html: true
```

Comment: Nice answer, thanks for the effort, but for me, it's enough to remove the <p> tag ;)